# Change name and image of wordpress blog when sharing it on social networks

Tags: facebook, wordpress, blogs

How can I change the name and the image that appear when sharing blog URL  made on wordpress on facebook?

I create the blog using www.wordpress.com, it's free.

From where I can change the name and the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the information that is previewed / shared on facebook by defining open graph tags. For more information on this see facebook's Developer docs [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

You can preview, and clear the cache of, data facebook holds with the [linter tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Note: I haven't used wordpress.com but hopefully you can implement these.

Comment: That's totally correct.The problem was with browsers and facebook cashing. Every thing works today in a perfect way. Thank you.